# open iTerm drop down console on different screen

Tags: macos, menu-bar, iterm

I use iTerm since a few days, and when i press my hotkey, it'll drop down nicely, from top of the screen, but ... on the wrong one.

I have a macbook pro with mountain lion, and i connect it to a 24" screen for development. It would be awesome if it can dropdown on the big screen if it is connected.

This might be a more general thing, since any menu bar of any app is showing on the small screen, instead of the external.

(ps. I use both screens, not in mirror mode obviously)

Any ways around this?

Comment: Crikey, i missed this all the time. But it's in preferences -> display -> drag the menu bar to other screen. I never realized (or cared to read the xplanation text) that you could drag that menu bar.

Comment: write that up as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crikey, I missed this all the time. But it's in preferences -> display -> drag the menu bar to other screen. I never realized (or cared to read the explanation text) that you could drag that menu bar.

Comment: This doesnt help much for me. Even though my "menu bar" is on the right screen, iterm appears on mostly random monitors every restart. Im assuming you are talking about the system preferences here

Answer (score 9):

iTerm2 Build 1.0.0.20130319:

Iterm->Preferences->Profiles->Window

From there you have a screen bar you can set to 'screen2' or 'main screen'.

Comment: This worked for me to change which screen the dropdown terminal was on using OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Is there a way to open the window always on the active screen?

Comment: This is the right answer. @degill default behavior is to start and stick on the screen from which you start iterm. There is also an option to appear in the  "Screen with Cursor". One of these two are probably what you want.

Comment: I tried "Screen with Cursor" but even this only controls the first appearance..